# I2c device open failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I follow a tutorial in interfacing BNO055 sensor.
It was connected to my Odroid C4 via SCL (pin 5) and SDA (pin 3) and also 3.3V & Gnd.
Ran command `sudo i2cdetect -r -y 0` returns shows the address to be 0x29.

Ran the launch file and errors showed up.

`
PARAMETERS

- /imu/imu_node/address: 40
- /imu/imu_node/device: /dev/i2c-0
- /imu/imu_node/frame_id: imu
- /rosdistro: noetic
- /rosversion: 1.15.14`

`setting /run_id to 159765cc-9bc4-11ec-b5b8-001e06489d9b process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6737] started core service [/rosout] process[imu/imu_node-2]: started with pid [6744] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what():  i2c device open failed`

`[imu/imu_node-2] process has died [pid 6744, exit code -6, cmd /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/lib/imu_bno055/bno055_i2c_node __name:=imu_node __log:=/home/odroid/.ros/log/159765cc-9bc4-11ec-b5b8-001e06489d9b/imu-imu_node-2.log].`

`log file: /home/odroid/.ros/log/159765cc-9bc4-11ec-b5b8-001e06489d9b/imu-imu_node-2*.log`

I have already edited the launch file, changing the device path to `/dev/i2c-0` and also the address to `0x29`.

Thank you.

Answer:
For `i2c device open failed`, run command `sudo chmod 666 /dev/i2c-0`

For `incorrect chip id`,Change the launch file address to
`<launch> <node ns="imu" name="imu_node" pkg="imu_bno055" type="bno055_i2c_node" respawn="true" respawn_delay="2"> <param name="device" type="string" value="/dev/i2c-0"/> <param name="address" type="int" value="41"/> <!-- 0x29 == 40 is the default for BNO055 --> <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="imu"/> </node> </launch>`

*0x29 is 41 and 0x28 is 40

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397084/i2c-device-open-failed/) by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-03-06**:
anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The linux account you are using to run ROS probably does not have read-write permission for the device `/dev/i2c-0`. As a quick hack, you can issue this command:

`sudo chmod 666 /dev/i2c-0`

but this will need to be repeated if you reboot the machine.

The better thing to do is to create a `udev` rule which will change the permissions on this device each time the machine boots.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-03-07**:
Thanks for replying. after running `sudo chmod 666 /dev/i2c-0`, the error message changes `what():  i2c device open failed` to `what():  incorrect chip ID`.

The full error:
`PARAMETERS

- /imu/imu_node/address: 40
- /imu/imu_node/device: /dev/i2c-0
- /imu/imu_node/frame_id: imu
- /rosdistro: noetic
- /rosversion: 1.15.14`

`NODES /imu/ imu_node (imu_bno055/bno055_i2c_node)`

`ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311`

`process[imu/imu_node-1]: started with pid [4568] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what():  incorrect chip ID`

`[imu/imu_node-1] process has died [pid 4568, exit code -6, cmd /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/lib/imu_bno055/bno055_i2c_node __name:=imu_node __log:=/home/odroid/.ros/log/dec645e4-9e44-11ec-bc5c-001e06489d9b/imu-imu_node-1.log].`

`log file: /home/odroid/.ros/log/dec645e4-9e44-11ec-bc5c-001e06489d9b/imu-imu_node-1*.log ^C[imu/imu_node-1] killing on exit shutting down processing monitor...`

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-03-07**:
decimal 40 is not equal to hex 0x29.

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-03-08**:
Hi there, I missed out on that as I am still learning. I changed it to 41 and it seems to be working now when and there are values to be seen and changes when the sensor is being move when running `rostopic echo /imu/data`.
Although rviz shows error for imu  when subscribing imu to topic `/imu/data`.
Thanks again.